# Java - Applet / Pop-Up Text Rendering

Tags: java, swing, text, applet, popup

I'm having trouble troubleshooting a display issue I'm seeing in some pop-up windows, and it seems to be Java related. I'm on the latest JRE (no new updates available from java update), have tried clearing my Java cache, and have the latest drivers and updates for my laptops. However, when viewing the "Configure Java" popup, text is missing on the buttons

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP6Rf.jpg]

The first button on the right should say "About", but only displays "A." The button with the "V" should say "View," and the left-most button on the bottom should say "OK" (not to mention the missing "Y" in "Apply").

Aside from this pop-up, I've only seen the issue appear in java applets.  I thought it might have something to do with my display resolution (1920x1080), however switching this around to smaller resolutions has not resolved the problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check your video card is using the latest drivers..

Comment: @AndrewThompson my card has the latest drivers from Nvidia.  This is one of the first things I updated to try and resolve the issue since it appears somewhat related to that..